# Mac App release and update checking outside App Store

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

My app has 2 versions: Mac and iOS. The iOS version recently gets passed of review.

But I can't release the Mac version to the App Store because it uses CGEvent that against App Sandbox.

My question is:

> 1. On which app markets or web sites can I release my Mac app so users can download it? Can I put the app on somewhere like Dropbox?
>
> 2. How to check updates? I am individual developer, I don't have my own web server. Is there any platform provide developers to manage app updates?

Please give me your advice, thanks!

Comment: You can get your own server, they aren't really expensive anymore. As for updates you can use [Sparkle](https://sparkle-project.org)

Comment: @HAS Which web server do you recommend? Linode?

Comment: I can't really answer that for you, mine is at domainfactory which is a German company because we have very strict privacy / data protection laws in Germany, forcing us to keep specific data on severs located in Germany.

Comment: @HAS I see, thanks for your advice! I think I can use Github Pages to finish my work, because I only need to provide a xml file and a dmg file if I use Sparkle, no database will be need. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah that sounds like good plan, exactly!